# Cannot install java module for my nodejs app in amazon ec2 instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, npm

I am using node 4X ,python 2.7.10 ,java jdk 8.I have installed all dependencies like gcc .

The build error is as below

http://pasted.co/283da73e

Why is the build failing. I had no problem with it on my windows machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're installing an older version of the `jdbc` module that depends on an older version of the `java` module that does not support node v4+. Update the `jdbc` dependency version and it should work.

Comment: I was stuck at this for 2 days.It solved the problem. Than you